# d3-tip library in Typescript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript

I am a newbie to typescript and was trying to include d3-tip library (https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) to my project. Normally, I would use

```
declare var [name_of_library]: any;
```

to let the compiler know the namespace, but d3-tip seems to be injected under the `d3` namespace:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module with d3 as a dependency.
        define(['d3'], factory)
    } else {
        // Browser global.
        root.d3.tip = factory(root.d3)
    }
}(this, function (d3) {  
    ...
```

What is the correct way to use d3-tip in Typescript project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3.d.ts you have

```
declare var d3: D3.Base;
```

This means to add to `d3` you simply add to `D3.Base` so:

```
declare module D3 {
    export interface Base{
        tip: any;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using TS 1.6.3 and trying to implement this on d3tip.js and I am getting a duplicate d3 declaration error. I am not sure I understand this solution. Do I paste these two blocks at the top of the file? Can you comment?

Answer (score 2):

With the current structure of the d3.d.ts file (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3/d3.d.ts), this is how you'd accomplish it now:

```
declare module d3 {
    export var tip: any;
}
```

The "correct" solution, however, is to write a full type definition file. The above is simply a quick way to silence the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

For me such thing works with angular 4 (typescript 2.2, @types/d3:'^3.5.5' @types/d3-tip: '^3.5.5' "d3": "^3.5.5","d3-tip": "^0.7.1",)...

```
declare var d3:any;
import 'd3';
import * as d3tip from 'd3-tip';
d3.tip = d3tip;
```

I agree it is a bit strange.., but however it works.